# Difference between virtual interfaces with ifconfig and iproute2

Tags: networking, interface

I am wondering what is the difference between:

```
# ifconfig eth0:0 1.1.1.1/24
```

and just

```
# ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev eth0
```

Btw I cannot do

```
# ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev eth0:0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

In `ip addr show` it appears differently :

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000 
link/ether 8c:ae:4c:fe:1f:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 1.1.1.1/24 brd 1.1.1.255 scope global eth0:0 ---> with ifconfig
inet 2.2.2.2/24 scope global eth0 ----> with ip
```

When should I prefer the first way and when should I prefer the second way? It seems more cool to

Comment: On Linux you should always prefer the iproute2 tools (like `ip`) and avoid the net-tools (like `ifconfig`), net-tools are deprecated. This does not hold true for other operating systems, though. For information in the thread [net-tools future](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2009/03/msg00780.html).

Comment: I know it is deprecated, I was just wondering if the two commands has the same result or not. Thanks for the thread is looks interesting.

Comment: If you insist on labels you can do it with ip as well: ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 label eth0:0 dev eth0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux, use the `ip` commands. In other OSes, use `ifconfig` and family.

If you use the [`iproute2`](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html) way (`ip`) as such:

```
ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev eth0 label eth0:0
```

you should have the same effect as your first `ifconfig` command, and should even be displayed the same way by `ifconfig`. As mentioned, in Linux, you should prefer the `ip` family of commands over `ifconfig`, `route`, etc. Though `ifconfig` and others will remain a stable in network admin's diets for a while to come because of their wide usage and support in non-Linux OSes as well.

Comment: I am exploring this option, could you please share how to make this rule persistent. I tried creating new interface file with the name eth0:0 but doesn't work.